# Is there a java library for APT?

Tags: java, apt

Is there a java library providing an API for APT (Debian Advanced Packaging Tool) like *python-apt* (see http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/) but for java?

Answer (score 0):

### I'm a Java programmer too, and I can answer:

**Unfortunately not**. I search for the 4 seas (or the 20th page of Google, if you prefer) and I could not find anything like that.

Now I'm looking for a library APT for Ruby, but I think I will start learn Python. I don't know why we can't find another libraries of the same function. While no one create, the way is learn Python and use python-apt.